# `bower install` failing always, open network

Tags: node.js, bash, proxy, bower, bower-install

Bower installing is always failing showing ETIMEDOUT and ESOCKETTIMEDOUT many times. I have disabled all the bash env proxy variables and npm proxy variables. Right now I am on open network without any proxy. All others are working well and fine like npm install, wget, etc

Here is the `.bowerrc` file:

```
{
  "directory": "www/lib",
  "registry": "http://bower.herokuapp.com"
}
```

here is the bower install log

```
bower                            retry Request to http://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/ionic failed with ETIMEDOUT, retrying in 1.2s
bower                            retry Request to http://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/ydn.db failed with ETIMEDOUT, retrying in 1.9s
bower                            retry Request to http://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/ngCordova failed with ETIMEDOUT, retrying in 1.1s
bower                            retry Request to http://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/angular-mocks failed with ETIMEDOUT, retrying in 1.9s
bower                            retry Request to http://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/angular-md5 failed with ETIMEDOUT, retrying in 1.5s
bower                            retry Request to http://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/angular-translate failed with ETIMEDOUT, retrying in 2.0s
bower                            retry Request to http://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/angular-translate-loader-partial failed with ETIMEDOUT, retrying in 1.8s
bower                            retry Request to http://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/angular-aria failed with ETIMEDOUT, retrying in 1.3s
bower                            retry Request to http://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/moment failed with ETIMEDOUT, retrying in 1.9s
bower                            retry Request to http://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/jszip failed with ETIMEDOUT, retrying in 1.8s
bower                            retry Request to http://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/oclazyload failed with ETIMEDOUT, retrying in 1.2s
bower                            retry Request to http://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/ckeditor failed with ETIMEDOUT, retrying in 1.2s
bower                            retry Request to http://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/angular-ckeditor failed with ETIMEDOUT, retrying in 1.5s
bower                            retry Request to http://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/angular-messages failed with ETIMEDOUT, retrying in 1.7s
bower                            retry Request to http://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/ngCordova failed with ETIMEDOUT, retrying in 2.8s
bower                            retry Request to http://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/ckeditor failed with ESOCKETTIMEDOUT, retrying in 3.5s
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
"proxy":"http://<host>:<port>",
"https-proxy":"http://<host>:<port>",
"strict-ssl": false
```

Comment: akoglu , I am not on any proxy :/ , so why should I include it

Comment: Your exception is very populer with proxy and i thought if you change your configuration, problem can be changed